# JSONException - Parsing String to JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse, parsing

i want to parse some json downloaded from the web in a JSONArray.
Simple thing i think, but can't get it to work.

It seams that the JSON Format is the Problem. I tried different ways
to fix it, but nothing helps.

I download the String with this method:

```
private String DownloadContent(String URL) {

    String result = null;
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", e.toString());
    }
    return result;        
}
```

After that i try to parse the string to the JSONArray like this:

```
String resultString = DownloadContent(stringUrl);
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(resultString);
```

but everytime i get this exception:

[image: exception]

i test the following to get the JSON right:

```
result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
result = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
```

this methods changed the string but no time the JSON is valid (tested with [this](http://jsonlint.com)).

In my JSON are things like this:

```
Meine gr\\u00f6\\u00dfte Leidenschaft ist es
http:\\/\\/bla.de\\/wp-content\\/uploads\\/2014\\/02\\/hello.jpg
```

What should i do to get it right? I hope someone can help me :)
Thanks!

Comment: why do you need this `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the `detailMessage`, it looks like you are trying to create a `JSONArray` from JSON that looks like

```
{"posts": [...]}
```

That's a JSON object, not an array. You'll need to parse it as a `JSONObject` and get the array object from it.

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(resultString);
JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("posts"); // or whatever the method is to get a JSONArray element from the JSONObject
```

This is assuming you are trying to get the JSON array named `posts`.